# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000003

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports

I have completed developing a Swift application using iOS SDK 8.1 and it is now being tested by external testers via TestFlight as beta. Recently, I have received a crash report via Crashlytics with the following stack trace:

```
 0 libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 28 setRefreshControlState:
 1 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
 2 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout + 16
 3 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_after_timer_callback + 92
 4 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout + 16
 5 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 792
 6 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_source_invoke + 288
 7 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 424
 8 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
 9 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
10 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
11 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 168
12 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 1488
13 opsgenie AppDelegate.swift line 0 top_level_code
14 opsgenie AppDelegate.swift line 0 main
15 libdyld.dylib start + 4
```

I could not replicate the issue neither on my own device, nor on simulator and this crash has happened only once in three weeks. I have no idea about what may cause this crash and what this crash report means. I have also analysed my custom Crashlytics logs which are generated, however, everything seems normal and I still have no idea about the problem. I know it is nearly impossible to understand the problem by only having this stack trace on hand, but any recommendation/idea would be very useful.

Comment: Did you get the Crashlytic log associated to this crash ?

Comment: @natuslaedo, did you find any exact reason and a solution to this? Facing similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are using pull to refresh , while the content is loading user is going to another view hence the crash.try to replicate it on a slow connection while doing pull to refresh.you can make sure you handle startRefreshing, endRefreshing methods properly

Comment: Hey @Ers, How did you interpret this? Can you explain it? I would like to know more

Comment: from this:  0 libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 28 setRefreshControlState:  setRefreshControlState method controls that